# Is there any way to make my JavaScript code more logical and efficient? How to convert functional to OOP in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, tooltip, minify

I created some tooltips using `javascript` but after writing the code I found it a lot more complicated and hard to read/understand is there any way to shortened my code and make it more logical and efficient.

```js
var tooltip = (function () {
    'use strict';
    const PREFIX = 'data-tooltip';
    const SUFFIX = ['pointer-direction', 'position', 'content'];
    const REQUIRED_ATTRIBUTES = [];

    SUFFIX.forEach((item) => {
        REQUIRED_ATTRIBUTES.push(PREFIX + '-' + item);
    });

    const POSITIONS = [
        'top-left-corner',
        'top-center',
        'top-right-corner',
        'right-center',
        'bottom-right-corner',
        'bottom-center',
        'bottom-left-corner',
        'left-center',
        'middle',
    ];

    const DIRECTIONS = [
        'top-start',
        'top',
        'top-end',
        'right-start',
        'right',
        'right-end',
        'bottom-start',
        'bottom',
        'bottom-end',
        'left-start',
        'left',
        'left-end',
    ];

    DIRECTIONS.forEach((direction, position) => {
        if (direction === 'top-start') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'top') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'top-end') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        }

        if (direction === 'right-start') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'right') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'right-end') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        }

        if (direction === 'bottom-start') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'bottom') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'bottom-end') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        }

        if (direction === 'left-start') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'left') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        } else if (direction === 'left-end') {
            if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'top-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'right-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-right-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'bottom-left-corner') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'left-center') {
            } else if (POSITIONS[position] === 'middle') {
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

> I know the code is quite huge but it is what it is.

Apart that, How can I check which elements **inside body** have same attribute presented in `REQUIRED_ATTRIBUTES` array.

**You can see or download the entire code from this [link](https://gist.github.com/KunalTanwar/bb01947f112febede391fd64bc8f1f81)**

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ could be a better place for this

Comment: @Gnqz Thanks for the suggestion. but the limit of posting is `65536` and my code is bigger than that  `70971` this is only code what about explaining my problem text.

Comment: @Gnqz your question is about optimization of written code - you don't need exact code block. Limitations to SE are not justification - Please trim down post as I will be requesting this be migrated to [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oops - should have been tagged @KunalTanwar.

Comment: @Elysiumplain just added! Thanks for suggestion. 

Answer (score 1):

maybe using class or break each section functionality code into separate specialized functions helping you to make your code maintainable and easier to update in future

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @behnam rahimpour! But if I know how to break this code I wouldn't post my question on **SO** on the first place. Lmao.

Answer (score 0):

u can use libraries for that like jquery it helps u to make it with simple code
[working fiddle](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=fca6d7bb4268)

```
var timeout;

function hide() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    $('.map-location-details').fadeOut(400);
  }, 400);
};

$('.map-point').mouseover(function () {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $(this).siblings('.map-location-details').fadeIn(400);
}).mouseout(hide);

$('.map-location-details').mouseover(function () {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}).mouseout(hide);
```

Comment: I don't want to use `jQuery` and apart that I am making custom tooltips for myself.

Comment: @KunalTanwar - If you don't want to use jQuery, don't add the jQuery tag to your question.